# Why does appending values to a vector from inside a loop only return the last values?

Tags: loops, vector, rust

**Update**
Thanks to everyone for the help. I think I'm near done, but I'm getting an error that read_one() implicitly returns () as its body has no tail or return expression. Any ideas?

```
use::std::io;
use::std::collections::HashMap;

fn read_one() -> String {
    let mut words = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut words)
        .ok()
        .expect("Failed to read line.");
}

fn main() {

    let mut tax_rates = HashMap::new();
    tax_rates.insert("AL".to_string(), 0.04);
    tax_rates.insert("AK".to_string(), 0.00);
    tax_rates.insert("AZ".to_string(), 0.056);
    tax_rates.insert("AR".to_string(), 0.65);
    tax_rates.insert("CA".to_string(), 0.725);
    tax_rates.insert("CO".to_string(), 0.029);
    tax_rates.insert("CT".to_string(), 0.635);
    tax_rates.insert("DE".to_string(), 0.00);
    tax_rates.insert("DC".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("FL".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("GA".to_string(), 0.04);
    tax_rates.insert("HI".to_string(), 0.04);
    tax_rates.insert("ID".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("IL".to_string(), 0.0625);
    tax_rates.insert("IN".to_string(), 0.07);
    tax_rates.insert("IA".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("KS".to_string(), 0.065);
    tax_rates.insert("KY".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("LA".to_string(), 0.0445);
    tax_rates.insert("ME".to_string(), 0.055);
    tax_rates.insert("MD".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("MA".to_string(), 0.0625);
    tax_rates.insert("MI".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("MN".to_string(), 0.06875);
    tax_rates.insert("MS".to_string(), 0.07);
    tax_rates.insert("MO".to_string(), 0.0425);
    tax_rates.insert("MT".to_string(), 0.00);
    tax_rates.insert("NE".to_string(), 0.055);
    tax_rates.insert("NV".to_string(), 0.0685);
    tax_rates.insert("NH".to_string(), 0.00);
    tax_rates.insert("NJ".to_string(), 0.06625);
    tax_rates.insert("NM".to_string(), 0.05125);
    tax_rates.insert("NY".to_string(), 0.04);
    tax_rates.insert("NC".to_string(), 0.0475);
    tax_rates.insert("ND".to_string(), 0.05);
    tax_rates.insert("OH".to_string(), 0.0575);
    tax_rates.insert("OK".to_string(), 0.045);
    tax_rates.insert("OR".to_string(), 0.00);
    tax_rates.insert("PA".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("RI".to_string(), 0.07);
    tax_rates.insert("PR".to_string(), 0.115);
    tax_rates.insert("SC".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("SD".to_string(), 0.045);
    tax_rates.insert("TN".to_string(), 0.07);
    tax_rates.insert("TX".to_string(), 0.0625);
    tax_rates.insert("UT".to_string(), 0.0485);
    tax_rates.insert("VA".to_string(), 0.043);
    tax_rates.insert("VT".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("WA".to_string(), 0.065);
    tax_rates.insert("WV".to_string(), 0.06);
    tax_rates.insert("WI".to_string(), 0.05);
    tax_rates.insert("WY".to_string(), 0.04);

    println!("In what state are you making your purchase?");
    let state = read_one();
    let state = state.trim().to_uppercase();

    println!("How many items are you purchasing?");
    let mut purchase_number = read_one();
    let mut purchase_number = purchase_number.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    match tax_rates.get(&state) {
        Some(rate) => {
            println!("The tax rate for {} is ({}).", state, rate);
        }
        None => {
            println!("None.");
        }
    }

    let mut tax_vec = Vec::new();
    let mut cost_vec = Vec::new();

    for item_number in 0..purchase_number {
        println!("What is the cost of item number {}?", item_number);
        let item_cost = read_one();
        let item_cost = item_cost.trim().parse::<f64>().unwrap();

        match tax_rates.get(&state) {
            Some(rate) => {
                let tax_amount = item_cost * rate;
                let fin_cost = item_cost + tax_amount;
                println!("The tax amount for item {} is: {:.2}", 
                item_number, tax_amount);
                println!("The final cost of item number {} is: {:.2}",
                item_number, fin_cost);

                tax_vec.push(tax_amount);
                cost_vec.push(fin_cost);
            }

            None => {
                println!("None.");
            }
        }   
    }

    println!("{:?}", tax_vec);
    println!("{:?}", cost_vec);
}
```

**Original Question**
I'm new to Rust (and coding in general) and messing with a simple program that calculates the state sales tax on a number of purchased items. Before closing, I wanted the program to total all the tax and all the final costs. I'm trying to store the values in two vectors and print them out, but for some reason it only returns the last values.

How can I print the total tax and total cost for the user?

Comment: You create a new vector each iteration, then you print the value only on the last iteration. Instead, create the vectors before the loop.

Comment: You probably also want to print the sums *after* the loop finishes. Doing so would have caused a compiler error that points out that `tax_vec` / `cost_vec` aren't available there.

Comment: As a first pass, here's [one way of rewriting it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6590a6532ebffd9f1474ce4a3fe20d72)